# Use Overflow in FlatList

Tags: css, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-web

I have a dropdown menu inside all items in FlatList
However, the menu from the last item will cut off by the FlatList container.

After debugging on Chrome, I found that adding `overflow: 'visible'` to FlatList's `div` works. But I have no way to override it.
I tried

```
<FlatList
  ...others
  contentContainerStyle={{ overflow: 'visible' }}
/>
```

and

```
<FlatList
  ...others
  style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', overflow: 'visible' }}
/>
```

but none of it work.

Here's what I see in Chrome inspector

```
<div> // style changes backgroundColor here, but ignoring overflow
  <div /> // contentContainerStyle changes this div
</div>
```

Heres my code:

```
  <FlatList
    ref='flatList'
    data={data}
    extraData={someData}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
    CellRendererComponent={({ children, index, style, ...props }) => {
      return (
        <View style={[style, { zIndex: data.length - index }]} index={index} {...props}>
          {children}
        </View>
      )
    }}
    style={{ overflow: 'visible', backgroundColor: 'red' }}
    enableEmptySections
  />
```

Comment: Can you post your complete code, I have two questions here,
1. Are you using react or react-native
2. If React-native you should be using View rather than div.

Comment: 1. I am using react-native-web, which allows me to use my react-native code in react

2. The `div` I post is something i see in Chrome inspector, updated the question